# Rails 4 user_id is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :recovery
end

class Recovery < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :email
end

class RecoveriesController < ApplicationController
  def create
      @user=User.find(19)
      @recovery=@user.create_recovery!
       if @recovery.save
        redirect_to :root
      end
  end
end
```

After create `@recovery.user_id` is `nil` in database

But if I remove the redirect, as here

```
class RecoveriesController < ApplicationController
  def create
      @user=User.find(19)
      @recovery=@user.create_recovery!
  end
end
```

user_id take its value.

Whats wrong? Rails 4

Answer (score 0):

Here is what should work:

In Your RecoveriesController:

```
class RecoveriesController < ApplicationController
  def create
      @user=User.find(19)
      @recovery = Recovery.new(user:@user) 
       if @recovery.save
        redirect_to :root
      end
  end
end
```

And, I am sure You have it, but that is not listed in Your Recovery model:

```
belongs_to :user
```